# How can I ask a conditional auto encoder to put more emphasis on the condition without setting epochs too high?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, autoencoder

Here's an example of what I'm testing on. I have the mnist digits data and I randomly add a random number from 1 to 10 to each digit and divide it by 11. I do this because I wanted to test out the results of the conditional auto encoder.

I use the means of each digit as the condition and set up a keras conditional auto encoder. Just to visualize it better, I set up the latent dimension to be 12 and perform Umap and plot it.

50 epochs: the latent space is clustered by the random digits that I added (0-10)

5000 epochs: the latent space now clusters by the digit labels

I want the the latent space to cluster by the digits, however 5000 epochs takes around an hour to run. For my actual application, this is not feasible. Is there any way to make the auto encoder emphasize on the conditional node?